# Can't pass type Object[] as param for method in Android AIDL

Tags: java, android, android-service

Here is the code:

```
package android.os;

import android.content.Intent;

interface IInterpreterService {
    int notifyChange(String rule_name, Object[] data);
    void getMonitor(in Intent intent);
}
```

The strange error is:

```
Aidl: framework <= frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/IInterpreterService.aidl
frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/IInterpreterService.aidl:7 parameter data (2) unknown type Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AIDL supports only limited set of types and Object is not one of them.
Specs also mentiones Parcelable as component in List. For that you will need
to define your type in separate AIDL.
Details can be found here
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html